# switch statement cause sending two messages

Tags: c++, udp, ros, winsock2

I have a UDP message sending socket in my Windows 10 laptop, I am trying to send a JSON to be decoded on ROS.
I wrote down a basic user entry function from command line, if I enter 1 it will send JSON with hello, if I enter 2 it will send jasonn with hi.
The problem is it sends bot hi AND hello message packages when I enter 1.
I do not know the reason , whether wrong logic on switch statement or something wrong with sendto() function of winsock2.

```
userDialog::UserEntry getUserEntrySendMessage(SOCKET myUdpSocket, sockaddr_in rosBridgeUdpAddress, int addrLen, int BufLen)
{
    std::cout<<"please enter what do you like to do:\n";
    std::cout << "enter 0 to connect ROSpberry Pi \n";
    std::cout << "enter 1 to send HI to ROSpberry Pi\n";
    std::cout << "enter 2 to send HELLO to ROSpberry Pi\n";
    std::cout << "enter 3 to finish \n";
    std::cout << "enter one of those in all UPPERCASE, "
        << "this code does not have an error check yet!\n";
    userDialog::UserEntry userInput{};
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    userInput = static_cast<userDialog::UserEntry>(x);
    switch (userInput)
    {
    case userDialog::CONNECT_ROS:
        {
        //creating the JSON message to be sent for initiating the topic
            const char* SendBufSTART = { "{ \"op\": \"advertise\",  \"topic\": \"myTopic\",  \"type\": \"std_msgs/String\" \}" };
            std::cout << "I will send this : \n" << SendBufSTART << "\n"; //quick check if JSON is correctly constructed
            sendto(
                myUdpSocket,
                SendBufSTART, //this will be our json 
                BufLen,// this will be json buffers length
                0, //no flags
                (SOCKADDR*)& rosBridgeUdpAddress,
                //sizeof(rosBridgeUdpAddress)   );
                addrLen);
            return userDialog::CONNECT_ROS;
        }
        break;
    case userDialog::SAY_HI:
    {
        //creating the JSON message to be sent to be published inside the topic
        const char* SendBufHI = { "{ \"op\": \"publish\", \"id\": \"metin's laptop\",  \"topic\": \"myTopic\",  \"msg\": \{\"data\": \"HI from metin!\"\} \}" };
        std::cout << "I will send this : \n" << SendBufHI << "\n"; //quick check if JSON is correctly constructed
        sendto(
            myUdpSocket,
            SendBufHI, //this will be our json 
            BufLen,// this will be json buffers length
            0, //no flags
            (SOCKADDR*)& rosBridgeUdpAddress,
            //sizeof(rosBridgeUdpAddress)   );
            addrLen);
        return userDialog::SAY_HI;
    }
        break;
    case userDialog::SAY_HELLO:
    {
        //creating the JSON message to be sent to be published inside the topic
        const char* SendBufHELLO = { "{ \"op\": \"publish\", \"id\": \"metin's laptop\",  \"topic\": \"myTopic\",  \"msg\": \{\"data\": \"HELLO from metin!\"\} \}" };
        std::cout << "I will send this : \n" << SendBufHELLO << "\n"; //quick check if JSON is correctly constructed
        sendto(
            myUdpSocket,
            SendBufHELLO, //this will be our json 
            BufLen,// this will be json buffers length
            0, //no flags
            (SOCKADDR*)& rosBridgeUdpAddress,
            //sizeof(rosBridgeUdpAddress)   );
            addrLen);
        return userDialog::SAY_HELLO;
    }
        break;
    default:
        return userDialog::DIALOG_FINAL;
    }
    return userDialog::DIALOG_FINAL;
}
```

Comment: What consumes the result of getUserEntrySendMessage? Could that be using your return value to send a different message?

Comment: I'd like to second the comment above regarding `BufLen`. Could it be large enough that it's sending both SendBufHI and SendBufHELLO (which are likely stored next to each other in memory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> BufLen,// this will be json buffers length
> ```

But it's not!

You send `BufLen` bytes regardless of which message is being sent.

It's likely that this is *too large* and you're accidentally overrunning `SendBufHI` into a string literal that happens to live next to it in memory.

Send only the bytes that you want to. That could mean `strlen(SendBufHI)`.

Comment: Another example of comments telling a lie, and the only thing telling the truth is the actual running of the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Technically, the comment is accurate: it describes a future state of the source code ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know why but strlen returns the value excluding null terminator, I had to use it withouth a -1 on the end.